# Matplotlib: Connect points generated by loop with line

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, curve

my code looks something like this:

```
%matplotlib inline 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for x in np.arange(0,100,5):

plt.scatter(x, x**2, c="blue", marker="o",s=1)


plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("$x$", fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel("$f(x)$", fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

which gives me the attached picture:
[image: plot]

How can I connect the points with lines, or even more preferably, a smooth curve?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`plot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) to create a smooth line rather than [`scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html), which plots the individual points. Also, you do not need to do any loops here, matplotlib handles the plotting of arrays.

```
x = np.arange(0, 100, 5)

plt.plot(x, x ** 2, c="blue")

plt.xlabel("$x$", fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel("$f(x)$", fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

**Edit**

I don't think there is a way to join the points directly using scatter. You could do

```
plt.scatter(x, x ** 2, c="blue",s=1)
plt.plot(x, x ** 2, c="blue")
```

which is essentially

```
plt.plot(x, x**2, color="blue", marker="o")
```

which is the same as @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer

Comment: Ok, I realized my question was a bit misleading. I don't want to use plt, but I'm asking for a specific way to do it with scatter.

Answer (score 0):

A `scatter` plot shows individual points of (potentially) different size and color. It seems that in this case, you want to have line `plot`.
Second, there is no reason to loop over the individual points from the array. Instead you want to supply the complete array to the plotting function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,100,5)

plt.plot(x, x**2, color="blue", marker="o",ms=5, label="label")


plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("$x$", fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel("$f(x)$", fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

[image]